# IIS set up new site with different port

Tags: iis, iis-7

Hi I'm trying to create a new site on IIS 7. Everything works fine except that I use a different port 8088 for this new site. I can browse the site on server via localhost:8088. However, I cant access from a remote machine via *ip_address:8088*. Did I miss anything?

Comment: The Windows firewall usually blocks port 8088, did you open it?

Comment: 99% you have a firewall issue.  Either on the machine where IIS is installed, or even on at the router / physical firewall level.  Easiest way to test is just to disable firewall and see if that fixes it, then create appropriate rules.   Also can test to see if your router is blocking requests by doing a trace to the device ip from a different machine.